# i am so curious about naming IEEE standard network,like why do we use "802" these three numbers?

Tags: network, ieee-802.11

I learnt some information about networks in Wiki,and I am so curious about naming IEEE standard networks. As far as I know:

The standard name of Wifi is 802

The standard name of Ethernet is  802.3

The standard name of Wireless LAN is 802.11,and 802.11a/b/g/n/ac after 802.11

I want to ask

1. Why do we always use the "802" to name the standard network? Why do we insist on using these three numbers,instead of other number like "123","456" ,or "789" these three numbers?
2. Why did we name standard name of Ethernet  802.3? Why don't we name it 802.2,or 802.9,is that .3 means the ethernet is the "third" standard network we discuss?or?
3. 802.11ac is faster than 802.11n,

   802.11n is faster than 802.11g,

   802.11g is faster than 802.11b,

   so 802.11a/b/g/n/ac is like the evolution of 802.11, I want to ask why should we use  "a,b,g,n and ac" to describe the evolution of 802.11? why don't we just use a,b,c,d,e,f to describe the evolution of 802.11? Easiser to remember and determine which is faster.

Comment: This is historical trivia. (and you appear to have put zero effort into researching it.)

Comment: because no book and wiki explain why

Comment: See the above linked question and its answers.

Comment: Actually, 802.11a is much faster than 802.11b, and it was defined first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE organize their work into *working groups* or *committees*, one of which is *P802* for LAN/MAN technologies. *802* was simply the next available number when that group was formed, although they first met in February 1980.

These form working groups for more specific topics such as *802.3* for Ethernet, *802.11* for wireless LAN, or *802.1* for higher-layer LAN protocols (spanning tree, link aggregation, VLAN, ...).

*Projects* or *study groups* then get successive letter codes a-z, aa-az, ba-bz, etc, like *802.3ab* for 1000BASE-T (1000 Mbit/s Ethernet  over twisted pair copper). Each of these projects define a standard or an addendum of the same name. Of course, not all of them are new physical layer variants.

Later standards often define faster versions than previous ones, but that is not always the case (e.g. *802.3bw-2015* 100BASE-T1 came much later than *802.3an-2006* 10GBASE-T).

Basically, you'll have to look up or remember what each letter code means.